# How to do internal links in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, google-colaboratory

I would like to make a reference list with the sections of my Colab notebook. The notebook is saved in my Google Drive.

I am trying HTML and Markdown hyperlinks, which work fine if the link is to an HTTP URL, but it is not working for internal Sections in the notebook.

For example, in a text cell I set the outline:

```
1. [Section 1](#s1)
2. [Section 2](#s2)
```

and in the destination section:

```
<a id='s1'></a>
#Section 1

.....

<a id='s2'></a>
#Section 2
```

The hyperlink in the list of the outline it is showed as a hyperlink but when I click on it or it does not do anything, or it opens a new tab in the browser with an error message:

[image]

Colab creates its own Content list using the markdown sections and subsections but internal links from one section to another are not possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With Colab you have to insert an `<a name="id"></a>` tag in the cell you want to link to.

The link works like normal:

```
[Link Text](#cell-id)
```

And the destination cell with the tag would be:

```
<a name="cell-id"></a>
# Heading
This is the cell I'm linking to
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm having the same problem as OP. Nothing happens when I click the link.

Comment: This works perfectly in my Google Colab notebook

Comment: Be sure to use `<a name=...` because `<a id=...` won't work.

Answer (score 9):

If you look close to your current colab url

```
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/BLAHBLAH?authuser=SOMENUMBER#scrollTo=BLOCKADDRESS
```

Every block has its own #scrollTo address.
Try clicking other blocks.
So,
I use it like

```
1. [LINK TEXT](#scrollTo=BLOCKADDRESS)
```

This way you don't have to put id tags

Answer (score 3):

I Create the internal links, in colab, as follows:

1. In the source text cell:

`<a href="internal_link"> text of the link</a>`

2. In the target cell:

`<div class="markdown-google-sans"><a name="id-link"></a></div>`

Note: I used 'name' instead of 'id' because 'id' doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The following lines worked for me

Origination: text
Destination:

A typical mistake must be the use of " ". If you look at my above lines carefully, it applies "" for the destination line Link, whereas not for the origination line.

Please do not add " " like "#Link" in the origination, otherwise it will direct you to the "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist." page.

Comment: Thank you. Would you mind posting a complete example?. I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Please try the following code, which I tested and worked 

Origination:
 1.  [Section 1](#s1)
  2. [Section 2](#s2)

Destination:
#Section 1  <a name="s1"></a>
#Section 2  <a name="s2"></a>

I hope it's clear now